# Buffer list messed up by dired-do-search in Emacs 24

Tags: emacs, emacs24

The behavior of `dired-do-search` (A) and `tags-loop-continue` (M-,) has changed in Emacs 24.

If the search reaches the end of the tagged buffers, the visible buffer in Emacs 23 remained the last one in which the search string was found. In Emacs 24 the last search is lost and another buffer (not clearly which) becomes visible.

How do I recover the previous behavior in Emacs 24?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this ugly hack:

```
(defadvice tags-loop-continue (around protect-search-end activate)
  (let ((oldbuf (current-buffer)))
    (unless (ignore-errors ad-do-it t)
      (switch-to-buffer oldbuf)
      (message "No more matches..."))))
```

This [around-advice](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Around_002dAdvice.html) remembers the current buffer and potentially restores it if the actual execution of `tags-loop-continue` signals an error, which we [trap with `ignore-errors`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Handling-Errors.html).

Comment: This works perfectly: It leaves the sequence of search results in the buffer list such that if I (bury-buffer) repeatedly after a search concluded, I look at the buffers where the search string was found -- in reverse order. Would you care to add two sentences explaining your code?

Comment: The code is actually quite simple once you understand around-advices and trapping errors. I've added the relevant links to the manual, but I recommend `C-h S` for consulting the Info pages faster

Comment: Just a sec... This works after C-u i "-alR", but it doesn't in a dired buffer with a single directory and a few files marked.

Comment: Do you mean that it _only_ works _after_ running `C-u i "-alR"`? Does it fail on a freshly built dired buffer? I am not sure I understand the exact context where it fails. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I managed to fix a small bug on the code. Please try it again.